# Returning a combineLatest observable from a function with an argument

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm not really sure if I'm doing this correctly.

I have a simple `function` that has an `argument` which I want to use inside a `combineLatest` observable. That observable is then returned.

```
  fn(arg) {
    return combineLatest([
      observable...,
      observable...,
    ]).pipe(
      map(() => arg)
    );
  }
```

The issue here is that when the function is called many times, it creates duplicate observables.

What would be the proper solution? To make the argument an observable too? So the function is only called once but it returns the correct value when the argument changes.

Comment: can you create a stackbliz for this, it would be really helpful to undersatnd and resolve your issue

Comment: it sound like you are not using the Observable correctly in the first place. The entire concept allows for an Observable to provide a stream of values over time that a consumer then consumes. It sounds as if you are trying to use Observables as Promises. You can certainly do that (return a promise) from your obvserable - then, once it resolves it would no longer duplicate. Alternatively, you can unsubscribe from the Observable and that might work too (depending on how things are written in your app).

Comment: @RandyCasburn You might be entirely correct. What would you suggest? I don't think converting it to a promise is a solution. A promise is only run once but I want to listen to changes that happens inside the combineLatest observable.

Comment: Would needs lots more detail about how your app works, the observables are created, what type of subject they are, and on and on. `observable...` doesn't mean anything and provides no insight.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I understand. I will update the post later today when I'm finished at work. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I noticed with Observable issues, when something is happening multiple times, it's usually incorrect or forgotten `unsubscribe`. Maybe check that too

Comment: @Unknown to call observable only once you can use take(1) inside pipe(), this will ends stream after function call. So no duplicate observable for every function call, combineLatest only runs when first time all observable atleat emit value, and afterwards any observable emit stream gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is not use `Observables` this way. Use a `Subject` for that kind of things:

```
readonly actionSubject = new Subject<unknown>();

...

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.actionSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(newValue => 
      combineLatest([
        observable...,
        observable...,
      ]).pipe(map(() => newValue)),
    )
  ).subscribe();
}


...
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.actionSubject.complete();
}
```

And in place of your function usage instead of `fn`:

```
this.actionSubject.next(someNewValue);
```

What happens here? `SwitchMap` will stop you old thread and start new one every time you have new value. That's solution.